Why no bracha on telling the story of the Exodus?
Relating the story of the Exodus is a Biblical commandment.  Why is there no bracha on specifically that?
An answer on this site says that we talk about the Exodus in the kiddush, but that does not address the question just posed.

https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/71959

@shmosel I did not understand most of the answers but I liked the bracha at the end "Baruch Ata, ... The King of the world, who sanctified us with his commandments and ordered us to remember the heroic deeds of the King of Kings, who performed miracles for our ancestors in Egypt on this night for Abraham, Isaac and Jacob, blessed are you, O Lord, who remembers the covenant."

The Hagaddah of R. Yaakov Loeberbaum (author of Nesivos HaMishpat), Maaseh Nisim, says the following:

ומה שנראה לתת טעם במה שלא תיקנו ברכה, כי עינינו הרואות שבכל דבר שתיקנו ברכה בגוף המצוה לא תיקנו ברכה על צוותו העשיית המצות, כי אינו בדין לתקן בברכה על ברכה. דהא ברכת המזון גם כן מצות עשה דאורייתא היא ולא תיקנו לברך אקבמו"צ לברך על המזון. אלא ודאי מטעם שכתבתי כיון שמברכין השי"ת בגוף המצוה אינו בדין לתקן ברכה על ברכה. ומטעם זה לא תיקנו ג"כ כאן כיון שכבר תיקנו ברכה אגוף הגאולה, והוא ברכת אשר גאלנו לא תיקנו עוד ברכה אחרת על זה.
It seems [to me] to give a reason regarding that which they [the Rabbis] did not affix a bracha, since we can see that anything that the bracha is done as the body of the Mitzvah, they did not affix a bracha on that which he commanded us to do the mitzvah. It wouldn't make sense to make a brach on a bracha. For instance, Birkat Hamazon is a biblical Mitzvah, and the Bracha "he who commanded us to bless Him for our food" is not made, since it wouldn't make sense to make a bracha on a bracha. Likewise here, they didn't make for the body of the Mitzvah, since they already formulated a bracha on the redemption itself - אשר גאנלו. [The Bracha said at the end of Magid.]

In essence, we don't make a bracha on making a bracha. The Hagaddah can in essence be boiled down to the bracha אשר גאלנו, which really encompasses the entirety of the story "we were slaves and God redeemed us", and therefore we don't make a bracha on magid.
There are other answers, including the one you mentioned in your question. But this one is (I think) the most famous.

Its a famous question. The answer in you're question, is since you already fulfilled the mitzva in kiddush the bracha cant be before you fulfill the mitzva. And it cant be before kiddush since we wont make a bracha before another bracha. Others explain that the bracha of kiddush is going on sippur as well.
The Rashba is brought by maise nissim and abudraham that says mitzvos without a shiur dont have brachas. Some explain that to mean by saying the bracha you already fulfilled the mitzva, when you mentioned mitzraim in the bracha, so cant say the bracha before the mitzva.
The Sfas Emes says because sippur is a logical mitzva to thank hashem for the nissim so even without hashem command we would do this so cant say the bracha, which implies we're doing it because of hashems command.
Some explain that the mitzva of sippur is really part of matza, therefore the bracha on matza covers it.
Rav Mordechai Gifter and ponovetzher rav learn sippur is part of mitzvas talmud torah, so bracha on Torah covers it, or bracha in haggada on torah.
